# MATLAB Fill area between lines on handled figure

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, fill

I am preparing a GUI with MATLAB. I have two plots on my GUI. 
I want to fill area between two series on each plot. In regular plotting, It is easy with `fill` function. My problem is, I can't do that with handled figure on GUI. 
How can I fill the area between two series on handled figure in GUI?
Thanx.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the axis handle, say `ha`, then you can use [`fill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) as follows:

```
fill(x,y,c,'Parent',ha)
```

Alternatively, you can use `axes(ha)` to select the axis, but this is slower:

> `axes(H)` makes the axis with handle `H` current.